# Unable to start my first app with ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, npm

I beginning to learn about the ionic platform and have been following the getting started instructions on their website but have run into problems when trying to start my first application.

Here's what I've done so far:

1 - `sudo apt-get install npm`

2 - `sudo npm install -g ionic@latest`

here I got 2 warnings

`npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /ionic/chokidar/fsevents:`

and

`npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.1.3`

Next I tried

`ionic start --pro-id <id i got from my ionic dashboard>`

and got the following error

`/usr/bin/env: ‘node’: No such file or directory`

Is there something I missed? Would appreciate any suggestions, thanks

Comment: I think you need to install node first and then ionic and cordova both

Comment: Ok, thanks. Where could I find info on how to do this? This is my first time using ionic (and npm for that matter).

Comment: did you refer this?  https://ionicframework.com/docs/intro/installation/

Comment: Remember that you'll need to install the **cordova** as well, before start a new app: `sudo npm install -g cordova`

Comment: ahh thanks @MustafaLokhandwala I was actually following https://ionicframework.com/docs/pro/basics/getting-started/ and didn't notice any mention of the cordova and node requirements... thanks for the help ;)

Comment: glad that it helps. Happy Coding :)